# 2018 Macbook Pro High Sierra: filesharing from other Mac causes crash on shutdown on this Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, crash, shutdown

**Update: Problem has been drastically narrowed down.**

After a lot of testing I've been able to narrow down the original question as it was first written to one issue:

Activating filesharing on my older Mac, then copying files between the older and this newer 2018 15 MBP causes a crash on shutdown on this newer Mac.

What kind of physical networking doesn't matter, it happens on both Ethernet and Wifi.

I ticked both boxes on the older Mac with FS enabled: AFP and SMB, as the newer Mac doesn't connect if just AFP is active. It can see the machine but not connect. I'm not sure if AFP was still supported in High Sierra ?

Networking itself between Macs is not the problem as I can use the Teleport application for keyboard/mouse control between Macs without issue. It's filesharing between machines that leaves this machine in a state that it can't shutdown properly

So the question has changed to what is causing this crash and is there anything that can be done to remedy it ?

I've attached the screen in Verbose mode where it hangs on shutdown. Sorry it's the best shot I could get.

[image: crash verbose shutdown]

Original topic was: 2018 Macbook Pro High Sierra/spinning wheel/Crash on shutdown

I recently acquired a 2018 MBP which came with Big Sur on it. It was working perfectly. I installed High Sierra 17G2208 which I downloaded from Apple's repository as I needed to run some older software. The install seemed to go fine.

But since then I have been experiencing a perpetual spinning wheel/crash when doing Apple Menu>Shutdown or Restart or sudo shutdown from Terminal.

When trying to shutdown the machine usually it looks as if it is starting to prepare for shutdown normally and then the keyboard lights up, the screen goes dark and there is a spinning wheel cursor and it stays there indefinitely.

I can't see anything too anomalous in the system log around shutdown time. The logs don't look that different to the system log shutdown in my older mac. Although I can post relevant segments here if need be.

Over the last I week I have consumed a vast amount of information on this kind of problem on this SE site, Apple's discussion site and elsewhere. To be honest I have become over-saturated and exhausted reading about this stuff, but I have not found a working solution from anything I've read.

Here's what I've tried so far:

PRAM/NVRAM reset: **Did not work**

SMC reset: **Did not work**

Safe boot:  Machine is virtually unusable in safe mode and so all I could do is leave it for a while and restart normally which I did.  After a couple of hours from being normally booted again I went to shutdown and it: **Did not work.**

Uninstall Little Snitch: This was one of the first things I had installed. It was mentioned in the system log at the time of shutdown, and others often advise removing LS with its uninstaller while troubleshooting. I did. Result: **Did not work.**

I tried this:

```
sudo rm -f /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist
sudo rm -f /private/var/db/.AppleUpgrade
sudo rm -f /private/var/db/.SoftwareUpdateAtLogout
```

as has been widely posted online, but the latter two files do not exist, while deleting com.apple.loginwindow.plist: **Did not work.**

I created a new user user account to test the machine with: TL;DR: **Did not work.** Long version: Opened a few different apps, saved a few files, connected to wifi and so on. Left the machine for a few hours, came back to it. At first this seemed to shutdown normally. Aha I've got it thought!  So I thought I would create another new account, this time with admin privileges. Again I put it through its paces for a couple of hours and seemed to shutdown normally. Restarted again, and after 5-10 minutes of use this account hung on shutdown. Rebooted to original admin account. All I did in this session was transfer a file over to my other mac, and this time ran

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

in Terminal and the machine hung hard. No black screen. And the spinning wheel was no longer spinning but frozen.

So the result of creating new user accounts to test: **Did not work.**

sudo sysdiagnose: This is sometimes suggested as a diagnostic tool. I ran the command, it completed fully and I tried searching the results for relevant information like 'shutdown', but it's difficult for a non-engineer to extract much practical information from it.

---

At first I thought the shutdown hang was time dependent, i.e starting the machine up, opening textedit or notes and then shutting down within 5-10 minutes did not seem to invoke the bug, but tonight's testing has proved that **false**. The machine can hang on shutdown no matter how long it's been booted for and used.

Other potentially relevant info: I can't remote login to the crashed Mac from another machine when it has hung on shutdown to force a shutdown that way.  The machine won't accept ssh connections (yes the login/address is correct as I can login fine when the machine is up and running normally).

The result of running:

```
kextstat -l | grep --invert-match com.apple
```

is nothing. There are now no non-apple extensions loaded.

FileVault is **on**. I wonder if this has caused the problem. I am reluctant to turn it off <strike>because it may be faster to reinstall the system anew than decrypt the drive which has about 140GB on it so far.</strike> My understanding now is that on T2 Macs the disk is encrypted regardless of whether FV is on. FV is just a password.

There are generally no connected peripherals, apart from the odd USB flash drive with USB-C to old style adapter.   It makes no difference to the crash on shutdown if the USB-C power is in or not.

The machine had been completely refitted with a new keyboard, battery, screen and I think touch bar under the Apple warranty program.

When I installed High Sierra a week ago, the installation seemed to create a mysterious new APFS volume called 'Update' which is mounted along with Macintosh HD. The contents of this volume appears to contain firmware and NVRAM info. I can find only one reference to a volume called 'Update' being created in this way on the entire internet. I can only guess it is created as some sort of temporary volume to do with the installation , and it should not be there afterwards. I am tempted to open another question here about this. Whether it's related to the shutdown problem or not I do not know.

Running Disk Utility when the machine is booted normally reports no errors. <strike>But from Recovery a serious error was reported on the parent container volume. At that same time Macintosh HD was grayed out/unmounted, and not sure if that's what caused the error of the parent container volume.  Maybe it's just worth reinstalling and starting over.</strike>

**Update:** there no errors reported on the disk when booted into recovery but there are these 'crypto val' warnings.

I don't know, but I would like to be able to shut down/restart normally.  I hope it's not a T2/touchbar problem as I read these can be a serious problem to fix.

The machine seems to run flawlessly until it is told to shut down or restart.

**Update**: I cannot yet trigger the crash if I logout first and then shutdown.

I'm also now suspecting networking to be a factor. Connecting to another Mac that has file sharing and then shutting down seems very high probability of a crash on shutdown.

I appreciate any helpful insight. If we could keep answers to the specific problem rather than advice that I should not run an old OS and should install Mojave/Catalina/Big Sur it would be much appreciated.

Comment: 1. Does this occur only when booted into High Sierra, or on Big Sur as well? 2. Does the caps lock key light up when pressed while in the hung state? 3. When you mention “serious errors” in Recovery, did the Recovery OS have the High Sierra or Big Sur UI?

Comment: Have you run all the firmware updates for High Sierra, and applied all the updates to High Sierra?  It was released before the 2018 hardware was released - when you do software update you may have to choose show me more options (or something like that) - it'll want you to upgrade to Big Sur (just don't select that).

Comment: @pion Hi. I erased the disk before putting HS on, so there is no Big Sur now. When the machine came to me it had Big Sur on it, no it was not doing that. I've updated the question as I've done some more work on this since then and got more understanding on some issues. I can now confirm there are no serious errors when I mount and check Macintosh HD first and the mysterious extra 'Update' partition and then check the parent partitions. The disk passes, apart from 'crypto val' warnings.

Comment: @Mr R There are a couple of Security Updates possible 005 I think and then 006 but have been reluctant to install in case I make the situation worse. And if they are just fixes for some code exploit in Safari I will probably leave them. 17G2208 was the specific build for this machine... had to use the script installmacos.py, it's modified date on Apple's server was (I think) some time in 2019, so I'm wondering if Apple retro rolled in some updates to this build, but not the very latest ones from 2020. Also I've not yet been able to trigger crash if I logout first then shutdown.